# How to fix System Error : Duplicate Id in list in Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch, map, duplicate-value

I have an error Duplicate Id in list when executing my batch. I looked at different answers on the community but even when trying to implement them, I still can't fix my error.

To try to fix the error, I updated my code using Map. So my execute method when from this:

```java
public class BatchHealthcareJourneyStepsSync implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Set<Id> hcjTempIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Healthcare_Journey_Template__c> hcJourneyTempList = [SELECT Id FROM Healthcare_Journey_Template__c 
                                                                  WHERE Template_Last_Modified__c != null];
        
        for(Healthcare_Journey_Template__c hc : hcJourneyTempList) {
            hcjTempIds.add(hc.Id);
        }
        System.debug('hcjTempIds ' +hcjTempIds);
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name, Healthcare_Journey_Template__r.Name FROM HealthCare_Journey__c 
                                         WHERE Journey_out_of_date__c = true AND Healthcare_Journey_Template__c IN :hcjTempIds]); 
                                        
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<HealthCare_Journey__c> scope) {
        System.debug('#### UPDATED Scope Size ' + scope.size());
        
        Set<Id> hcjIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> hcjTempIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(HealthCare_Journey__c hcj : scope) {
            hcjIds.add(hcj.Id);
            hcjTempIds.add(hcj.HealthCare_Journey_Template__c); //Template Id
        }
        System.debug('xxxxxxx healthcare journey execute method ' +hcjIds);
        
        Map<Id, Step__c> stepMap = new Map<Id, Step__c>([SELECT Name, Step_Number__c, Template_Step__c FROM Step__c 
                                  WHERE HealthCare_Journey__c IN :hcjIds]);
        
        //get Template_steps
        List<Step__c> stepToUpdate = new List<Step__c>();
        for(Template_Step__c tStep : [SELECT Name, Step_Master__c, Step_Number__c, Step_Master__r.Name, Healthcare_Journey_Template__c,
                                     (SELECT Field, NewValue, ParentId FROM Histories WHERE Field = 'Step_Number__c '),
                                     (SELECT Name, Sub_Step_Number__c, Sub_Step_Master__r.Name FROM Template_Sub_Steps__r) 
                                      FROM Template_Step__c WHERE Healthcare_Journey_Template__c IN :hcjTempIds]) {
                                          
            //Update Steps
            for(Step__c stp : stepMap.values()) {
                stp.Name = tStep.Step_Master__r.Name;
                stp.Step_Number__c = tStep.Step_Number__c; 
                stepToUpdate.add(stp);
            }
              
        }
       
        System.debug('xxxxxx Steps update ' +stepToUpdate);
        if(stepToUpdate.size() > 0) {
            update stepToUpdate;
        }
     
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
       System.debug('Done'); 
    }

}
```

then below is the code using map. The problem here is that the information is passed to the record is incorrect. Basically, all the records are updated with the same value. Also the batch seems to run forever almost like an infinite loop

```java
public class BatchHealthcareJourneyStepsSync implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Set<Id> hcjTempIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Healthcare_Journey_Template__c> hcJourneyTempList = [SELECT Id FROM Healthcare_Journey_Template__c 
                                                                  WHERE Template_Last_Modified__c != null];
        
        for(Healthcare_Journey_Template__c hc : hcJourneyTempList) {
            hcjTempIds.add(hc.Id);
        }
        System.debug('hcjTempIds ' +hcjTempIds);
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name, Healthcare_Journey_Template__r.Name FROM HealthCare_Journey__c 
                                         WHERE Journey_out_of_date__c = true AND Healthcare_Journey_Template__c IN :hcjTempIds]); 
                                        
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<HealthCare_Journey__c> scope) {
        System.debug('#### UPDATED Scope Size ' + scope.size());
        
        Set<Id> hcjIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> hcjTempIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(HealthCare_Journey__c hcj : scope) {
            hcjIds.add(hcj.Id);
            hcjTempIds.add(hcj.HealthCare_Journey_Template__c); //Template Id
        }
        System.debug('xxxxxxx healthcare journey execute method ' +hcjIds);
        
        Map<Id, Step__c> stepMap = new Map<Id, Step__c>([SELECT Name, Step_Number__c, Template_Step__c FROM Step__c 
                                  WHERE HealthCare_Journey__c IN :hcjIds]);
        
        //Map to avoid error Duplicate Id in List...
        Map<Id, Step__c> stepToUpdateMap = new Map<Id, Step__c>(); 
        
        //get Template_steps
        List<Step__c> stepToUpdate = new List<Step__c>();
        
        for(Template_Step__c tStep : [SELECT Name, Step_Master__c, Step_Number__c, Step_Master__r.Name, Healthcare_Journey_Template__c,
                                     (SELECT Field, NewValue, ParentId FROM Histories WHERE Field = 'Step_Number__c '),
                                     (SELECT Name, Sub_Step_Number__c, Sub_Step_Master__r.Name FROM Template_Sub_Steps__r) 
                                      FROM Template_Step__c WHERE Healthcare_Journey_Template__c IN :hcjTempIds]) {
                                          
            //Update Steps
            for(Step__c stp : stepMap.values()) {
                stp.Name = tStep.Step_Master__r.Name;
                stp.Step_Number__c = tStep.Step_Number__c; 
                stepToUpdate.add(stp);
            }
              
        }
        stepToUpdateMap.putAll(stepToUpdateMap);
        System.debug('xxxxxx Steps update ' +stepToUpdate);
        if(stepToUpdateMap.size() > 0) {
            update stepToUpdateMap.values();
        }
     
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
       System.debug('Done'); 
    }

}
```

`//Database.executeBatch(new BatchHealthcareJourneySync());`

Comment: your logic is not making sense.   source of your error  for duplicate id is nested for loop.   you are iterating over   Template_Step__c    and then in inner for loop  you are modifying  every  Step__c   and adding it to list to updated.  by doing it n number of times     for each Template_Step__c       you are adding duplicates.   do you relayy need to update every step__c   everytime for   each   Template_Step__c    ?   it is not making sense.  what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok I see,
Thank you, what you just said will help actually. Let me review the code

Comment: sure.please review it  and post updated code  with result expected if you face any issue.